# How to safely change uid and gid for apache user (www-data) on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server

I have a quite specific situation where a migration needs to happen from one brand od linux to ubuntu 22.04. So far, so good. Among other things original setup have multiple users and respective directories that are tied to apache webserver user and/or group that has different uid and gid than one on Ubuntu. To minimize issues with permissions we are considering changing www-data uid and gid to the one of the original OS (48 both values from 33 original). The issue is when I try to do that I get following message:

```sh
sudo -- usermod -u 48 www-data
usermod: user www-data is currently used by process 717
```

So if I seek the files and directories tied to www-data this is the list

```sh
sudo -- find / -user 33

/proc/717
/proc/717/task
/proc/717/task/717
/proc/717/task/717/fdinfo
/proc/717/task/717/net
/proc/717/task/717/attr
/proc/717/task/717/attr/smack
/proc/717/task/717/attr/apparmor
/proc/717/fdinfo
/proc/717/net
/proc/717/attr
/proc/717/attr/smack
/proc/717/attr/apparmor
/proc/718
/proc/718/task
/proc/718/task/718
/proc/718/task/718/fdinfo
/proc/718/task/718/net
/proc/718/task/718/attr
/proc/718/task/718/attr/smack
/proc/718/task/718/attr/apparmor
/proc/718/fdinfo
/proc/718/net
/proc/718/attr
/proc/718/attr/smack
/proc/718/attr/apparmor
find: ‘/proc/2240/task/2240/fd/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/2240/task/2240/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/2240/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/2240/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
/run/apache2/socks
/run/php
/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock
/run/lock/apache2
/var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk
/var/lib/apache2/fcgid
/var/lib/apache2/fcgid/sock
```

Apache service is of course stopped

What is missing?

Comment: Stop `php-fpm`, this is the process using the user.

Comment: Bless you sir. If you add this as response I will accept it.

Comment: Really useful command here is `ps -p 717` with additional options (e.g. `-o exe,args`), with `sudo` if needed. You found `/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock` and I guess this is how the fellow user recognized the culprit was `php-fpm`. Your approach is not the best way of investigating such problems and in general it may give no result; in your case `php-fpm` does not even appear. If you know the PID then `ps` is the tool. Alternatively you could dig into `/proc/717/`.

Comment: But even if you didn't know the PID(s), `ps` would find them for you: `ps -u www-data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The daemon which is run (based on your log) is `php-fpm`. This daemon usually run as apache user so stop the daemon and try the operation again.

Do not forget to change the ownership of files after successfully change the UID.